# How to catch Fillo no record found exception(Java)

Tags: java

I want to check if the resultset is empty or not.

rs.executequery(query)

trows **com.codoid.products.exception.FilloException: No records found** exception if the file is empty

Now my question is how to catch, What Parameter (like in catch(NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION)) to use

```
com.codoid.products.exception.FilloException: No records found
at com.codoid.products.fillo.Recordset.<init>(Recordset.java:40)
at com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection.executeQuery(Connection.java:69)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isBeforeFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst--) to determine if a newly-returned [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) contains any rows.

> **Returns:** true if the cursor is before the first row; false if the
>   cursor is at any other position or the result set contains no rows

```
try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    // executeQuery never returns a null ResultSet

    if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
        // The result set contains no rows. Take some action.
        // log.error("No records found");
        // throw new Exception("No records found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I try the above code, it throws No Record found exception if the file is empty. I need to write a catch statement exclusively for No Record found exception.

Comment: How you report and handle the error is up to you. Simply replace the "throw" with your error handling code. Or, throw an exception and have the caller catch it and perform some action.

Comment: With Fillo execute query, I cannot use resultset. Instead I am using Recordset which gives exception while calling executequery(query)

Answer (score 0):

```
// We can catch the exception like below...
catch(com.codoid.products.exception.FilloException nrf)
{
    // Code to handle when No Record Found exception occurred...
}
```